# How can I analyze the impact of each browser extension on Gmail loading time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use a couple of Google Chrome Extensions to improve Gmail Web interface ([Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg/), [Streak](http://www.streak.com/), etc). Is there any way to analyze the impact of each browser extension on Gmail loading time? (without having to uninstall extensions)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few programs that can track the loading time for pages for you.  Programs like [Benchmarking Extension](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/chrome-benchmarking-extension) have many options to play with.

There is also a Chrome Extension called [Page load time](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-load-time/fploionmjgeclbkemipmkogoaohcdbig?hl=en) which measures page load time after *you* load a page. All the events are displayed with their individual load time.

**Additional Solution:**

GMAIL takes time to load the emails. It could be considered as a download. There are many plug-ins and options to track downloads. Setting a timer is easy.

It is a Chrome extension used by developers. It may be a little complicated to use. I haven't played with it so it may not wait for *extensions* to load on page. There's many options.

Disabling all extensions and loading one separately would give you some idea.

Either way, you could check how big an extension is and count the number of loops.

A small *efficient* script with a lot of loops will take as long to load as one with many definitions and resources.

There are many duplicates to this question : I have run the following search terms -> chrome with extensions loading time.